# How to scale a div to a responsive image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm making a responsive website and I want a image next to a div.
While placing the image next to the div is no problem, it gets tricky when I make my screen smaller.

I gave the image a width of 100% and a height of auto (responsive image) and this is the result:

[image: Right here you see the image fine]

This example is how it needs to be permanent, even when I scale it down.
Right now when I scale it down, this happens:

[image]

Because the image is responsive, it shrinks and the div stays in place.
Is there any way to make the div scale with the picture?

My CSS (Made in SASS):

```
.block-middle{
        background-color: $oranje;
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 85px;
        padding-left: 55px;
        padding-right: 55px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        padding-bottom: 87px;
        .button-wit-bruin{
            margin-top: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        h1{
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: 700;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
    }
    .block-right{
        img.liggend{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
```

And the HTML is simply:

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-p block-middle">
```

Comment: Use percentages in the css and wrap both in a container and scale the container so both stay the same height.

Comment: so, you want the div to always have same height as the image?

Comment: Please post the code that you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="img1_div"></div>
<img id="img1" alt="" />


<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $(window).on("load", function(){
            $(window).on("resize", function(){
                var imgHeight = $("#img1").height();
                $("#img1_div").height( imgHeight );
            }).resize();
        });//window load
    });//document ready
</script>
```

This code will work in most cases ( except there's no overriding behaviour ), no matter where your image and div are placed. I would like to mention though that resize and scroll events should not be handled crudely this way, but should be optimised using a global timeout variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh sorry I misunderstood your question. This can be done with a bit of flexbox if your target browsers support it. Is this the result you're looking for?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left-block {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}
.right-block {
  width: 50%;
}
.image {
  display: block; // Removes spacing around image cause by default display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-block">
  </div>
  <div class="right-block">
    <img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Previous Answer:**
It seems as though there's a height set on your `.block-right` element. The code you provided is rather incomplete as you're missing the markup for your `.block-right` element. But is this what you're looking for?

```css
.left-block,
.right-block {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-block {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.right-block {
  background: grey;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-block">
</div>
<div class="right-block">
  <img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
```

Comment: I want my div to be the same height as my image, no matter the size

Comment: Which div are you talking about? You have shown two divs in your question. the left one and the right one.

Comment: both divs, I think, are supposed to be the same height...sounds like he wants the div without an image to scale proportionately like the one that has an image.

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying @ryantdecker, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @kevinito if you throw `display:block;` on the image it should get rid of the couple of px offset that the div goes below the image.  @Gordy Colonna, I've also posted a way to do this if you need to support non-flexbox browsers.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to set the height of the div relative to the width...which ironically, you can't do with the height property, since `height:auto;` makes it the height of it's children.

`padding` however is relative to the width of the parent...so it's a little bit funky, but if you play with the padding-bottom as a % and make the height:0px; you can achieve the desired effect without using Javascript.  Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.responsive-background {
  float:left;
  width:60%;
  height:0px;
  padding-bottom:30%; /* adjust this depending on the height/width of the image you are aligning to */
}
```

And a Codepen with more detail and some additional styling:
http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/LZYYaj

I think this will do the trick for you.

Comment: Ahh, [Uncle Dave's Ol' Padded Box](http://daverupert.com/2012/04/uncle-daves-ol-padded-box/), one of my favourite little hacks.

Comment: Never seen Uncle Dave's version, but this is one of my favs, too - I've used it more than a few times.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is, use the image as background for div and use background-size as cover:

```
.right-block {
    background: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```